# Google + access token insufficient permission

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, oauth2-playground

Using OAuth code i am able to generate access token for google+ API .

using this access token in [oauthpalyground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) iam getting JSON response .

When I paste this this URL into a browser am get an error message.

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=%22great%22&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Error Message

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: try changing &access_token to &oauth_token=

Comment: `access_token` is the correct query parameter.

Comment: What scopes are you asking for when authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

You can not query directly from browser sending the access_token as a querystring. You must send access_ token in headers this way:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

Try it with Fiddler or some similar software.